# Calling stored procedure from Entity Framework - ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

In my ASP.NET MVC 2 project I'm trying to call a stored procedure from EF, the problem is after I followed the directions [here](http://dotnet-codeguru.blogspot.com/2010/02/call-stored-procedure-from-entity.html) (went this route because there's nothing in the model that maps to this stored procedure so I added 2 entities for the 2 stored procedures) I get this error:

> GCTModel.msl(3,4) : error 3027: No
>   mapping specified for the following
>   EntitySet/AssociationSet -
>   GalleryAnimalLists, GalleryImages.

Now, since I had to add manual entities to map these SP's to how do I get rid of this error message? And ideas on what I'm doing wrong here, or is this post on his blog just wrong for MVC 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting the hand rolled entities I created for the function imports and created 2 complex types and mapped the function imports to those and it works perfectly. Just thought I'd share the solution I came up with in case someone came along with a similar issue

Comment: Similar issue.  Beginning of each fiscal year, all data from last fiscal year handbook is copied to new Fiscal Year Handbook.  MVC makes one call to the DB for each row in every table with previous year's ID number.   OMG.  Why?  Takes like 5 minutes to complete.  WHY?!  One call to one stored procedure, and it would be nearly instantaneous.  I just want to call a stored procedure and return a true/false if successful. Just as I start to appreciate MVC, I learn to hate it all over again.